# Laptop overheats when connected to a network

Tags: networking, laptop, cpu, overheating

Whenever I connect my computer to a network, does not matter with wireless or ethernet cable, my CPU starts working 95+ celcius degrees but when disconnected it works fine, it almost imidiately drops to 40 - 50 celcius degrees max even when playing Skyrim or EU4 or PES2017 tepretures does not usualy go up from 70 degrees. It also does not overheat imidiately when I connect to a network until I start using the network, Steam, browser etc... But the second it starts comunicating on internet, CPU temp jumps up again. I tryed uninstalling both Ethernet and Wireless drivers and reinstalling them from the official laptops support web page. Disabled almost all services except for Microsoft. I am using Asus x550jk which I recently cleaned, and new cooling paste. None of them worked. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

screenshots of Task Manager, CPUID HW Monitor and Resource Monitor :

[ss1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvAUO.gif)
[ss2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsagm.gif)
[ss3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UuGo.gif)
[ss4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tf9Hq.gif)
[ss5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k86YZ.gif)

Comment: What does your taskmanager say is using the most system resources while you're connected? It sounds like you have a virus or other malware that works while the network connection is active. Have you checked for viruses? How? Using what tools?

Comment: Here are screenshots of TaskManager, CPUID HW Monitor and Resource Monitor :
https://ibb.co/ZJBWsqZ
https://ibb.co/RDM2Ypn
https://ibb.co/v1HwMJY
https://ibb.co/Qk24vbp
https://ibb.co/YkZR0DC

Comment: @AlpayAydıngüler - Those pictures are inaccessible.  Edit your question and use the image upload functionality within the editor.